# facebook ADK, android studio 0.8.2

Tags: facebook, sdk, android-studio

I add Facebook SDK into Android studio 0.8.2
It haven't error in code but have some error when I run the app.

```
==========================
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :facebook:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:facebook:compileLint
:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preBuild
:facebook:preReleaseBuild
:facebook:checkReleaseManifest
:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebook:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseJava
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:21: error: package bolts does not exist
import bolts.AppLink;
            ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:22: error: package bolts does not exist
import bolts.AppLinkResolver;
            ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:23: error: package bolts does not exist
import bolts.Continuation;
            ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:24: error: package bolts does not exist
import bolts.Task;
            ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
public class FacebookAppLinkResolver implements AppLinkResolver {
                                                ^
  symbol: class AppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    private final HashMap<Uri, AppLink> cachedAppLinks = new HashMap<Uri, AppLink>();
                               ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    public Task<AppLink> getAppLinkFromUrlInBackground(final Uri uri) {
           ^
  symbol:   class Task
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    public Task<AppLink> getAppLinkFromUrlInBackground(final Uri uri) {
                ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    public Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>> getAppLinkFromUrlsInBackground(List<Uri> uris) {
           ^
  symbol:   class Task
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    public Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>> getAppLinkFromUrlsInBackground(List<Uri> uris) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:178: error: package AppLink does not exist
    private static AppLink.Target getAndroidTargetFromJson(JSONObject targetJson) {
                          ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    private final HashMap<Uri, AppLink> cachedAppLinks = new HashMap<Uri, AppLink>();
                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
        Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>> resolveTask = getAppLinkFromUrlsInBackground(uris);
        ^
  symbol:   class Task
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
        Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>> resolveTask = getAppLinkFromUrlsInBackground(uris);
                      ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
        return resolveTask.onSuccess(new Continuation<Map<Uri, AppLink>, AppLink>() {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Continuation
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
        return resolveTask.onSuccess(new Continuation<Map<Uri, AppLink>, AppLink>() {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
        return resolveTask.onSuccess(new Continuation<Map<Uri, AppLink>, AppLink>() {
                                                                         ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
        final Map<Uri, AppLink> appLinkResults = new HashMap<Uri, AppLink>();
                       ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
        final Map<Uri, AppLink> appLinkResults = new HashMap<Uri, AppLink>();
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
            AppLink appLink = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
            return Task.forResult(appLinkResults);
                   ^
  symbol:   variable Task
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        final Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>>.TaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource = Task.create();
              ^
  symbol:   class Task
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        final Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>>.TaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource = Task.create();
                            ^
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        final Task<Map<Uri, AppLink>>.TaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource = Task.create();
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Task
  location: class FacebookAppLinkResolver
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:147: error: package AppLink does not exist
                                List<AppLink.Target> targets = new ArrayList<AppLink.Target>(targetsCount);
                                            ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:147: error: package AppLink does not exist
                                List<AppLink.Target> targets = new ArrayList<AppLink.Target>(targetsCount);
                                                                                    ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:150: error: package AppLink does not exist
                                    AppLink.Target target = getAndroidTargetFromJson(rawTargets.getJSONObject(i));
                                           ^
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
                                AppLink appLink = new AppLink(uri, targets, webFallbackUrl);
                                ^
  symbol: class AppLink
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
                                AppLink appLink = new AppLink(uri, targets, webFallbackUrl);
                                                      ^
  symbol: class AppLink
C:\Users\HuuLoc\AndroidStudioProjects\Har\libraries\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java:192: error: package AppLink does not exist
        return new AppLink.Target(packageName, className, targetUri, appName);
                          ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
30 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':facebook:compileReleaseJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.267 secs
=================================
```

Answer (score 0):

In your facebook/build.gradle file, change the line

```
compile files('../libs/bolts.jar')
```

to this line

```
compile files('libs/bolts.jar')
```